# Adding position of an item on a list to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I would like to add a number at the end of a item in the list i'm creating like so:

```
import datetime as dt

current_date = dt.date.today()
string_date = current_date.strftime(('%B%d%Y'))

listSONO = []
NumberOfLoops = 2
BaseSONO = "AutoSO_" + string_date

for x in range(NumberOfLoops):
    listSONO.append(BaseSONO)

print(listSONO)
```

i would like it to look like
[AutoSO_currentdate_01, AutoSO_currentdate_02, AutoSO_currentdate_03....]
And so on created for the number of loops mentioned above.
id be grateful for all help

Comment: `listSONO.append(BaseSONO + f"_{x+1:02}")`

Comment: `[f"AutoSO_{string_date}_{i}" for i in range(1, 11)]` you can use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Formatted String Literal (`f-string`)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
import datetime as dt

current_date = dt.date.today()
string_date = current_date.strftime('%B%d%Y')

listSONO = []
NumberOfLoops = 2
BaseSONO = "AutoSO_" + string_date

for x in range(1, NumberOfLoops + 1):
    listSONO.append(f'{BaseSONO}_{x:0>2}')

print(listSONO)
```

Furthermore, you could also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which may be more pythonic:

```
import datetime as dt

current_date = dt.date.today()
string_date = current_date.strftime('%B%d%Y')
num_loops = 2
list_sono = [f'AutoSO_{string_date}_{x:0>2}' for x in range(1, num_loops + 1)]
print(list_sono)
```

**Output for both versions:**

```
['AutoSO_May042022_01', 'AutoSO_May042022_02']
```